# 4 black wires for light switch box, 3 white w/ Picture

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

Was trying to replace light switch because old one was not aesthetically pleasing. Thought this was going to be easy as Ive done many before but was thrown off by so many black wires. Not sure what wire goes where and when I try to turn on the breaker it automatically trips back. Please help!!! [image][image][image][image]

Comment: just connect it up the way it was with the old switch

Comment: Hello Jordan, welcome to this Stack Exchange site. I suggest to post a higher resolution picture with less non-essential border. The current mini-picture at 320x240 is so small and blurry it is hard to see what is going on in the electrical box.

Comment: I really hope you took a picture **BEFORE** dismantling everything

Comment: do you have testing equipment? have you done any testing?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not take a picture how it looked before; dont have any testing equipment. Wonder how I can identify the different black wires?

Comment: Your best bet is going to be to call an electrician. They'll have the tools on-hand to figure this mess out for you. In order to figure this out properly you'll need at least $100 in tools and then spend time learning and troubleshooting.

Comment: If you have an idea of where the wires ultimately go then you can buy a wire tracer and trace everything yourself to figure out which is the power wire, travelers, or even simply pass-through.

Comment: It looks like the black wires on the right and left were maybe  wire-nutted together ???? and the very short wire pigtailed to the switch? Were the red wires connected to anything?   Is the part of a 3-way or 4-way switch circuit?  Please ad a picture of the old switch (back side).

Comment: @George Anderson thats exactly how it was except the pig tails on the right were nutted together and the one on the left was connect to switch by itself. But When I try to do this it trips breaker. The red wires and white wires were always in the back. I’m wondering if this was done correctly to begin with. Attached new pictures

Comment: OK, so no 3-way or 4-way switches involved.  Solving this is going to involve some detective work as to where the cables go.  BTW...why did you take apart the connections just to replace the switch?

Comment: I'd say call an electrically competent handyman. Most of us could git-r-dun... If you *had* to DIY, a $10 voltage tester, about $10 in random nuts/pigtails/etc., and a free book from the library (read most of it) could suffice.  The limiting factor is skill, and some humans can acquire new skills.

Comment: By the way, absolutely nothing goes on that green ground screw.  Nothing!  The switch gets its ground via the mounting screws into the stesl box, and will not use the ground screw.  That will solve your breaker trip problem.  That roached little 1" pigtail won't cut it, you will need at least 1 pigtail 6" long.  Black, #12, THHN solid wire will be fine.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

If your new switch is the same as the old you have skinned a wire or have hot touching ground.  You should be able to connect all of the black wires together and the light would be on all the time and not trip the breaker . The switch is a simple open closed device. 1 hot feeding another device and the switch to the light when the switch is in the on position all the wires are connected. You need to find the short, it could be by chance the lamp failed with a short , not likely but a possibility a skinned black wire touching the metal box will cause the breaker to trip.

Another possibility is a switch leg where white is used as a hot I cannot clearly see the rest of the wiring , if you only messed with the 1 pig tail (just black wires) look for the damaged insulation.

Comment: Is there any way to figure out which black wires get pig tailed and which wire should be by itself? Does the light switch have to have 2 black wires connected to it or will just 1 suffice?

Comment: Yes connect all but 1 when the light doesn’t light that single goes on the light by itself. You might get it on the first try or 4th but that’s not two hard to do , Mark the wires you test so you don’t loose track, fingernail polish great for marking